# Funktionsvereinigung oder Funktionenvereinigung

Tags: compound, mathematics

Die Vereinigung von Funktionen  und , die ()=() für alle  ∈ (dom )∩(dom ) erfüllen, ist die Funktion ⋓ ≝ (λ  ∈ (dom )∪(dom ). if  ∈ dom  then () else ()).

1. Wie würdet ihr ⋓ nennen und warum: Funktionsvereinigung oder Funktionenvereinigung? Im Netz fand ich beides in mathematischen Kontexten: http://d-nb.info/964096471/34#page=337 (Seite 317) und http://yumpu.com/de/document/read/26165053/systemmodell-basierte-definition-objektbasierter- (Seite 58).
2. Beide Wörter lassen sich wohl als „Funktion“+Fuge+„Vereinigung“ ansehen, stimmt's?
3. Lässt sich „Funktionenvereinigung“ zusätzlich als „Funktionen“+Nullfuge+„Vereinigung“ mit Pluralform „Funktionen“  ansehen?

Answer (score 3):

Das mit den Fugenlauten ist eine ziemlich komplizierte Sache. Der [Wikipedia-Artikel über Fugenlaute](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fugenlaut) gibt einen guten Überblick, aber letzten Endes läuft es immer auf dasselbe Prinzip hinaus, das hinter jeder sprachlichen Entwicklung steht:

Jeder Muttersprachler versucht seinen eigenen Sprachgebrauch an die Gewohnheiten der Mehrheit der Menschen anzupassen, mit denen er es zu tun hat. Oder als Empfehlung für Deutschlernende formuliert: Mach es wie die Mehrheit.

Das Problem dabei ist, dass jeder Mensch in einer anderen Gruppe von Menschen lebt, die ihm dieses Mehrheitsdeutsch vorsprechen und vorschreiben. Das hat zur Folge, dass in verschiedenen Regionen für dieselben Komposita unterschiedliche Fugenelemente verwendet werden. Beispielsweise werden in meiner Heimat (der Osten Österreichs) viele Komposita anders gebildet als in weiten Teilen Deutschlands. Hier ein paar Beispiele:

> D: Schweinebraten, Ö: Schweinsbraten
> D: Zugverspätung, Ö: Zugsverspätung
> D: verfassunggebend, Ö: verfassungsgebend
> D: Adventskalender, Ö: Adventkalender

Es gibt aber auch Unterschiede zwischen Berufsgruppen. Juristen sind ja berühmt-berüchtigt für ihre Sprache:

> Jurist: Hilfsleistung, Nicht-Jurist: Hilfeleistung
> Jurist: Schmerzengeld , Nicht-Jurist: Schmerzensgeld

Aber auch dort, wo über alle Ländergrenzen hinweg und über alle Berufsgruppen und sozialen Schichten hinweg dieselben Fugenelemente verwendet werden, lässt sich die richtige Wahl des Fugenelements nur schwer in Regeln fassen:

- Warum heißt es *Seelenverwandter* und *Seelsorger* aber nicht *Seelverwandter* und *Seelensorger?*
- Warum nennen sich viele Ausflugsgaststätten *Waldesruh* und nicht *Waldruh* obwohl kein *Waldesweg* sondern ein *Waldweg* hinführt?
- Warum bedeuten *Gasthaus* und *Gästehaus* nicht dasselbe?
- Warum bedeuten *Mauseloch* und *Mäuseloch* aber doch dasselbe?
- Wenn in einem *Kindergarten* mehrere Kinder sind, und wenn die *Kindesmutter* Mutter eines Kindes ist, warum heißt dann die Haushaltshilfe, auch wenn sie sich um nur ein Kind kümmert, nicht *Kindesmädchen* sondern *Kindermädchen?*
- Warum ist in *Geburtstag, Geburtsdatum, Geburtsstadt, Geburtsurkunde* usw. ein *s,* obwohl es doch gar keine grammatische Form des Wortes *Geburt* gibt, bei der ein *s* an das Wort angefügt wird?

Fragen über Fragen und auf alle gibt es immer dieselbe Antwort: Weil jeder einzelne Mensch diese Wörter so verwendet, wie die Mehrheit aller Kommunikationspartner, mit denen man zu tun hat.

Und bei der Frage, ob *Funktionenvereinigung* oder *Funktionsvereinigung* richtig ist, ist es dasselbe: Die, die in einer Blase leben, in der das Fugenelement -en- häufiger verwendet wird, werden *Funktionenvereinigung* sagen und schreiben, und das ist dann auch richtig. Und die, die in einer -s-Blase leben, verwenden eben *Funktionsvereinigung,* und in dieser Gruppe ist das auch richtig.

Und die Frage, nach welchem der beiden Muster

- Funktion - en - Vereinigung (Singular + en-Fuge)
- Funktionen - ∅ - Vereinigung (Plural + Nullfuge)

das Wort *Funktionenvereinigung* zusammengesetzt ist, kann man auch nur schwer beantworten, weil die Fugenlautbildung eben ganz anderen Regeln folgt als die sonstigen Deklinations-Arten.

---

Off-topic:
Was richtig und was falsch ist, kann sich aber auch im Laufe der Zeit verändern:

Ich habe oben das deutsch-österreichische Beispiel *Adventskalender/Adventkalender* vorgestellt. Tatsächlich nimmt aber in Österreich seit ca. 20 Jahren die Zahl jener Menschen stetig zu, die ein *s* in das Wort einfügen, so dass das Wort ohne *s* bald aussterben wird. Warum das so ist, ist leicht erklärt: Viele dieser Kalender werden in Deutschland hergestellt und mit dem Wort *Adventskalender* bedruckt und dann im ganzen deutschen Sprachraum, also auch in Österreich verkauft. Und die Werbung, die im Fernsehen und in anderen Medien dafür gemacht wird, verstärkt noch die Präsenz dieses Wortes in Österreich. Und weil jeder gerne so spricht und schreibt wie es ihr/ihm von ihrer/seiner Umwelt vorgemacht wird, tragen nun auch schon in Österreich für den österreichischen Markt produzierte Adventkalender den Ausdruck *Adventskalender*. Und die Österreicher, die jünger als ca. 40 sind, sagen auch schon mehrheitlich *»Adventskalender«,* während in meiner Generation (ich bin jetzt 56) noch mehrheitlich *»Adventkalender«* gesagt wird.

Comment: Danke! Ist die Kompositumbildung ‚Substantiv in Pluralform auf „-en“ + Nullfuge  + Substantiv‘ überhaupt grammatikalisch? Gibt es sonstige Beispiele dafür?

Comment: @GeekestGeek: Was genau meint du in diesem Zusammenhang mit "grammatikalisch?" Jedenfalls gibt es Komposita, die recht klar auf eine Pluralforn und eine Nullfuge zurückzuführen sind, wenn auch - wie gesagt - die Fugenlaute eine eigene Kategorie sind und an und für sich nur wenig mit Beugungsformen zu tun haben: Erbsenzähler, Griechenland, Soldatenfriedhof, Datenschutz. Und ganz ohne Zweifel (weil es gar keinen Singular gibt): Feriendomizil, Kostenersatz, Spesenabrechnung, Azorenhoch, Tropensturm.

Comment: Ok, danke für die Beispiele!